# Extract colored line from numpy image

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

I have an image that features a colored curve.

I want to extract for each row the index of the higher pixel of the curve.

This code works, but is quite slow (`f`is the image, `magic` is the RGB code of the line color):

```
res = f.shape[0]
magic = 146, 47, 6
return [min(l for l in range(res) if np.array_equal(magic, f[l, c, :3])) for c in range(res)]
```

How can I do the same thing faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare against `magic` elements along each row, i.e. last axis. This gives us a `2D` mask.

```
mask = (f == magic).all(-1)
```

Since, we are finally doing `min(l)`, that would mean finding the index of the first `True` in that mask array. So, if there's at least one guaranteed match, we could use `argmax` to get the index of first match, like so -

```
(f == magic).all(-1).argmax(0)
```

Comment: I found a trick: `(f[:, :, :3] == magic).all(axis=-1).argmax(0)`

Comment: argmax takes takes the first index that is true, so here it returns the min as expected!

Comment: Thank you for your help! I accepted your edited answer :)

Comment: @Labo I was not able to run your loop comprehension at my end and then I interpreted it wrongly, the first time around. A simple loop version would had been nicer to see what's going on, rather than cramping everything in one line, hurts the readability and I am not good with loop comprehensions :)